# how to make sure a Coldfusion object is only created once?

Tags: security, object, coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I have a `scheduled task` which should run every minute. To block the file from being called from outside, I want to compare host and calling IP adress like so:

```
 <cfif NOT structKeyExists( "variables", caller )>
    <cfset variables.caller = createObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress")>
 </cfif>

 <cfif variables.caller.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() EQ cgi.remote_addr> 
     // run task
 </cfif>
```

**Question:**
I'm not really used to working with `objects` in Coldfusion, so would this be a way to make sure the object is created once and re-created every minute when the task is being called? Since this is running in my admin section, should I create the object on application scope right away?

Thanks for some input!

Comment: why not set up directory permissions instead? that would save you a lot of overhead if this is being called every minute

Comment: hm. not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: @Russ gave you a good answer wrt ensuring that your cf file can only be called by the scheduled job.  As far as making sure the object is created each time the job runs, you don't have to do anything.  The object you create in a cf file gets destroyed once the file finishes executing.

Comment: @frequent how you set up permissions depends on your system. are you on windows or *nix? is this a shared server or do you have full control?

Comment: The server is hosted by another comp, I have a lot of access but no cfadmin. Anyway, your info on the object being created once the file has run is helpful. Make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a request even if the request is a scheduled task, all the variables are destroyed when the request has been completed. Only variables like session, application, and server persist between requests.

One approach to making sure that pages only run on the machine that they are on is to:

```
<cfif cgi.remote_addr EQ "127.0.0.1"> 
 // run task
</cfif>
```

Comment: I don't know how secure you want this to be.  I haven't tried this myself, but according to [this](http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2008/12/9/Spoofing-CGI-variables--Security-Series-11), it might not be the way to go.

Comment: ... pretty much what I came up with, too :-). Also thanks for the link @Barry.

Comment: If it's only supposed to be run as a scheduled task, I'd be looking at cgi.http_referring_agent.